# Why I get error implementing webfor at AMP, Drupal

Tags: drupal, webforms, twig, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

I get this error try to implement form in amp at Drupal for web form

> Only XHR based (via action-xhr attribute) submissions are support for
> POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

**This work for me**
At the twig web/themes/custom//templates/webform/webform-custom.html.twig

```
<form action-xhr="{{ url('<current>') }}" {{ attributes }}>
   {{ title_prefix }}
   {{ children }}
   {{ title_suffix }}
</form>
```

Comment: This didn't work cause the webform to use reCaptcha and the AMP validator get js to fail